# how to parameterize imagestreamtag in openshift YAML

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I have more than ten builds in my openshift project. Each build has a version in its build config. On a new sprint, I need to update the version in each build config individually which is tedious.

`output:
   to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: my-app-3.11`

I'm looking for a way to store the version number as shared variable across all configs, and change it once for all.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a "template" for the`ImageStreamTag`object with a "tag" parameter

[Link to the doc for templates in OC 3.11](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/templates.html)

Then "process" the template passing the "tag" parameter to create the yaml, and from then execute the resulting yaml to create the`ImageStreamTag`

When use this for many kind of objects